# Python - IDLE Crashes when Scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-idle

With Python 3.7.1 (installed with Homebrew) on macOS Mojave 10.14.1, whenever I scroll using the trackpad while using IDLE for python scripting, the IDLE window crashes. So much as moving along the trackpad in any way while in the IDLE window causes it to crash.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  I have Python 3.7.1 installed on my Macbook Air with the python.org installer.  Moving a finger around the track pad moves the cursor around, just like moving a mouse.  Moving the cursor over the scrollbar and pressing the lower right corner simulates a mouse click on the scrollbar.  What version of Tcl/Tk does Homebrew make 3.7 work with?  Check Help => About_IDLE.  Are you doing anything with the pad other that what I said above?  Have you changed any system settings?

Comment: When I open the file by double clicking in finder, IDLE crashes when scrolling with the mouse wheel. When opening IDLE first and then opening the file from the File Menu I can scroll in the same file without crashing. IDLE version 3.6.7 TKK 8.6.8, MacBook Pro 2018, 10.14.3

Comment: I have the same issue, installed using Homebrew

Comment: A bug report about this has been raised on the Python issue tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue37391 I don't think Stack Overflow can usefully help (and there isn't a specific question in your post anyway).

Comment: You can use ipython as alternative to idle. It runs in the terminal and has pretty all the same functionality, and looks good. I prefer using ipython over idle. Here you can read about it: https://ipython.org/install.html.